# How to find any string in a page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm desperately looking for a jQuery function to parse every string in a page (may be in a table) and replace its content with another one.

For example, i want to uppercase any string that is in a table row.

Couldn't find any clue on how to get started, would appreciate some starter help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a plugin that performs this task, but maybe this could be useful.

```
$("#mytable").replaceTableContents(origText, newText)

(function($){
$.fn.replaceTableContents = function(old, newt)
{
  if($(this).text().indexOf(old)>-1){ //check
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(){

      if($(this).text().indexOf(old)>-1){ //check

         $(this).find("td").each(function(){

            if($(this).text().indexOf(old)>-1){ //check
               $(this).html($(this).html().replace(old, newt));
            } 

         }
      }

    })
  }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query like this to get all text nodes and then do a loop over the collection. I would probably limit it just to the element that has the text you want to modify and not do it on 'body' as it probably will not be very performant.

```
var nodes = $("body")
              .contents()
              .filter(function() {
                  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will navigate over all the elements on the page, checking for text nodes.  You can then do something with them.

```
$(document).contents()
           .filter( function() { return this.nodeType == 3 } )
           .each( function() {
               ...process...
           });
```

To uppercase any string inside a table, though, I would use

```
$('table').contents().
          .filter( function() { return this.nodeType == 3 } )
          .each( function() {
              this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
          });
```

Comment: Cool, is there a link you can provide to see what other nodeType's you can test for?

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but with jQuery you don't need to iterate over anything to find table rows. In this case:

**CSS**

```
tr.upper{text-transform:uppercase}
```

**jQuery Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").addClass("upper");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here but remember that whatever you do, it will be imperfect because any word containing markup will appear as a normal word to the user, but will not match your search pattern.